# Is this point on all the solution of this ODE?

Tags: calculus

$$(y^2-1)\frac{dy}{dx}=x-1$$

Solving it I got $$\frac{y^3}{3}-y=\frac{x^2}{2}-x+c$$

From the ODE we know that $x=1, y=1$ makes the equation balance.
Does it mean to all the solution of this ODE, there must be a point $(1,1)$?

I know it is not, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a contour plot of the function $y^3/3 - y - x^2/2 + x$.

[image]

Solutions of the differential equation lie on these contours.  However, a solution (by definition) must be a differentiable function, so when the tangent to the curve becomes vertical (as it does on the lines $y=1$ and $y=-1$) the solution stops existing.
So for example the curve  $y^3/3 - y - x^2/2 + x = -2/3$
has vertical tangents at $(x,y) = (0,1)$, $(1-\sqrt{33}/3, -1)$, 
$(1+\sqrt{33}/3, -1)$ and $(2,1)$, and these points divide the curve into $5$ different solutions.

Since the differential equation is singular at $(1,1)$ but the two sides of the differential equation are both defined there, it is debatable whether to allow that point to be included in a solution.
In any case, there are only four solutions which have $(1,1)$ as a limit point.  The other solutions, if they are defined at $x=1$, have $dy/dx = 0$ there.